# Как использовать вместе QT & Code::Blocks?

Tags: codeblocks, qt, c++

Ребята, я только начал программировать на C++. Вот хочу попробовать его вместе с Qt, а как его использовать вместе с любимым Codeblocks не знаю, подскажите как?

Comment: Поставить [Nokia Qt SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) религия не позволяет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже рекомендую пользоваться QtCreator он работает отлично и заточен под Qt. Но если очень хочется использовать другую среду, то для начала достаточно прописать как шаги сборки следующую последовательность действий:
    qmake
    make

И, плохая новость, -- файл проекта *.pro придется редактировать вручную. Смотрите описание [формата и команд qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html#qmake)